# Which code adds a single point to the TernaryPlot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have installed the TernaryPlot package, and have an empty ternary diagram.

I want to add some points on it.

If i wrote the code *TernaryPlot(20, 30, 50)* it returns these numbers on the triangle as a vertex name, not a point on the plot .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Om0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detailed instructions can be found on the package vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ternary/vignettes/Using-Ternary.html
But for short, here is a minimal working example to add a point `P`:

```
TernaryPlot(atip = 'A', btip = 'F', ctip = 'M')
TernaryText(coordinates = c(20, 30, 50), labels = "P")
```

You should use `TernaryPlot()` only to create a new, void plot. To add some elements on an existing plot, other specific functions should be used.